# Android. Have scrollbar only visible if ScrollView is scrollable

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Is there a simple way to have the scrollbar in `ScrollView` only visible if the view is scrollable?

I know it's possible to achieve this by comparing the height of the `ScrollView` and the `ViewGroup` inside it and then calling `ScrollView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);`
but it's a lot of overhead and i feel like there should be a simpler and cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing the normal behaviour of a ScrollView. If the ScrollView is not scrollable the ScrollBar won't appear. Even  android:fadeScrollbars="false" won't take any effect if the view isn't scrollable. 
Maybe the only child of the ScrollView itself is to big to fit in the viewport (or the ScrollView container) In your case the ScrollView seems  to have always a scrollbar. You could test it by putting a simple TextView as a child in the ScrollView and adjusting the height.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [ViewTreeObserver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) to get the heights, because it will be called at the moment the layout / view is changing the visibility, otherwise the heights could be 0.

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id...);
ViewTreeObserver observer = scrollView.getViewTreeObserver();
observer.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int viewHeight = scrollView.getMeasuredHeight();
        int contentHeight = scrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
        if(viewHeight - contentHeight < 0) {
           ScrollView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        }
    } 
});
```

This is a clean solution IMO and there is no easier way than this.